# Unable to login into wolkenkit-boards app

Tags: wolkenkit

I tried to use wolkenkit-boards. I also setup an account on auth0 as described. When I use my own key, after filling username and password, It takes me back on login screen again and again. When I do not pass env variable - AUTH_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_URL and AUTH_CLIENT_ID then client side app assumes default credentials commited in source code. But in that case there is no signup option and we do not know username and password to login

Comment: Hey ! Did the answer of @mattwagl solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

First guess: Did you change the [auth0 certificate in the server folder](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-boards#getting-the-required-information)? If this is not the case, the server might try to validate the login token with the current certificate and then redirect you again to the auth provider because he thinks the token is not valid. The auth provider however thinks you're already authenticated and sends you back to your backend and you end up in an infinite loop of redirects. If you change this certificate you need to restart the backend.